# C++ namespace resolution

Tags: c++, namespaces, unnamed-namespace

When I try to build this code:

```
// foo.h
namespace foo {
    namespace bar {
        void put();
    }
}
```

```
#include "foo.h"
namespace foo {
    namespace {
        template<typename T>
        void put() { }
    }    
    void bar::put() {
        put<int>();
    };
}
```

[I get the error](http://ideone.com/m8DJax):

```
foo.cpp: In function ‘void foo::bar::put()’:
foo.cpp: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
foo.cpp: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘int’
```

Clearly, `put<int>` is using `put` to refer to `bar::put`. How can I make it refer to the `put<T>` in the anonymous namespace?

Comment: @bash.d: Yep, clumsy. Didn't get as far as parsing that. Edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could fully qualify the function template's name:

```
namespace foo {
    namespace bar {
        void put();
    }
}

namespace foo {
    namespace {
        template<typename T>
        void put() { }
    }
    void bar::put() {
        ::foo::put<int>();
    }
}
```

Also notice, that you don't need to use the semi-colon after a function definition.

Comment: Does it have to be `::foo::put`? `foo::put` seems to work as well, although I'm not sure whether that's just the compiler being lenient about things.

Comment: Semicolon was left over from narrowing down the problem. Whoops.

Comment: or `foo::template put<int>();` or `foo::put<int>();`

Comment: Any way that I can avoid mentioning `foo` to qualify the name?

Comment: @us2012: I think `foo::put` is enough in this case, but `::foo::put` is safer in case namespace `foo` contains another namespace called `foo` (maybe not the case here, still...)

Comment: @Eric: I don't think so. Not as long as both the function and the function template are called `put()`.

Comment: So declaring it as `void bar::put() {}` is not treated differently to `namespace bar { void put() {} }`? In the latter, it's obvious that `put` refers to `bar::put`, but I was expecting the former to have different resolution rules.

Comment: @Eric: Yes, I believe they are treated the same. They are alternative definitions of the exact same function after all, it makes sense that name resolution rules don't change.